# Blocking users from accessing my website by its ip

Tags: apache, url, web

Can I block from users if they type my server ip address instead of a dns domain.
Is that possible with httpd.conf?

Comment: If they just enter the IP address, no host header would be set.  One way to do this would be to setup your website as a virtual server based on the host header.  I'm not an Apache expert though, and there's a good chance there is a more elegant way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: How so? I can access it by typing the ip or the dns, I just want to block if anyone types the ip

Comment: You can configure virtual servers based on the host header, and have the "non-virtual server" (e.g. just the IP address) go to an empty website.  Looks like you have a simpler solution though as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not rewrite the URL if they don't use the FQDN?

You can put this into the httpd.conf or the root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^75\.222\.333\.444 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or, if you really want to dump the request completely, use this as the second line:

```
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Doesn't do Anything, this is what I added:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^5.xx.x.xxx [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomainexample.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Did you escape (backslashes) the dots between the IP classes?

Comment: Yes, like I pasted on the comment above